# How to maneuver black dragons over curved path in King's Bounty: Armored Princess?

Tags: kings-bounty-armored-princess

Black Dragons have the special ability of flying over a number of units in a line, burning each of them. I can use the ability just fine by landing the dragons in point A, then activating the ability, then clicking point B on the other end of a row of enemies in a straight line.

Except enemies rarely line up with neat empty spaces on two ends of their row. And enemy black dragons have absolutely no problem to fly up to my units leaned against the back of the map, then weaving in a twisting line over all my units, and landing on a free square in front of them - in other words, using that skill in a curving line. And I have no clue how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Units do not travel in straight lines, they are limited by a pattern that must be traveled in hexes.

Going from that idea, selecting a diagonal point as a destination, will move your unit a few hexes in one direction (0, n) till it gets to a point where it can travel in straight line towards final destination (another (0, m) hexes), appearing as it is traveling in a curve (exception is the enemy last line).

You can use that to maximize the number of creatures hit without them needing to be in a  straight line.

Traveling from the bottom line of the enemy to the top line of the enemy will make your dragon moving on the map "border", hitting all enemies.

The patterns are quite simple and you will get the hang of them fast, just activate the grid for an hour or so to see the hexes highlighted.

Comment: I use the hex grid at all times, and that means three different straight line directions (horizontal, diagonal right and diagonal left). The thing is if I use the special ability, I get to point to a place in any of these three lines. If I get there the ability is exhausted.

Comment: Yes, that is right. But you don't have to place the destination in any of the 3 straight directions you mentioned. You can place it anywhere. Also note that moving on the back enemy line the dragon will not move in a straight patter, instead it will follow the border.

Comment: ok, gonna try it in a couple days when I'm back to my PC, and accept if I get it right.